# Nested SQL statements pulling from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, html, count

I am trying to nest in SQL statements that are trying to pull data from two tables, counting rows from player_id, the rows from 1st_assist and 2nd_assist, displaying in 3 columns accordingly.

Here is my code.

```
SELECT 

     last_name, 

     (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM goals WHERE player_id = 4 OR player_id = 5) 
     AS player_goals, 

     (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM goals WHERE 1st_assist = 4 OR 1st_assist = 5) 
     AS 1st_assists, 

     (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM goals WHERE 2nd_assist = 4 OR 2nd_assist = 5)
     AS 2nd_assists 

FROM people 

WHERE player_id = 4 OR player_id = 5 

GROUP BY player_id
```

Comment: What's the question? What's the error? What happens/what do you expect to happen?

Comment: The error I get is "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM goals WHERE player_id = 4 OR player_id = 5) AS player_goals, ' at line 5"

Comment: What I want is to have an SQL statement that will get what I am looking for out of my tables.  That is, what I wrote up top.  Trying to get the 3 columns to add the number of rows that has player id 4 or 5 in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT 
    p.last_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) AS player_goals,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a1.id) AS 1st_assists,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a2.id) AS 2nd_assists
FROM
    people p
    LEFT JOIN goals g ON (g.player_id = p.player_id)
    LEFT JOIN goals a1 ON (a1.1st_assist = p.player_id)
    LEFT JOIN goals a2 ON (a2.2nd_assist = p.player_id)
WHERE
    p.player_id = 4 OR p.player_id = 5
GROUP BY p.player_id
```

Tested:

```
mysql> select * from people;
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| player_id | last_name | first_name |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
|         4 | Francis   | Jeff       |
|         5 | Doe       | John       |
|         6 | Barratt   | Glen       |
+-----------+-----------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from goals;
+----+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | player_id | 1st_assist | 2nd_assist | when_made           |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         4 |          6 |          5 | 2011-11-07 15:05:31 |
|  2 |         4 |          5 |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:05:37 |
|  3 |         5 |          4 |          6 | 2011-11-07 15:05:45 |
|  4 |         6 |          4 |          5 | 2011-11-07 15:05:52 |
|  5 |         4 |          6 |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:06:05 |
|  6 |         5 |       NULL |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:06:15 |
|  7 |         6 |          4 |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:06:21 |
|  8 |         5 |          6 |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:06:31 |
|  9 |         4 |       NULL |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:15:21 |
| 10 |         4 |          6 |       NULL | 2011-11-07 15:15:27 |
| 11 |         6 |          5 |          4 | 2011-11-07 15:15:38 |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+---------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT p.last_name, COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) AS player_goals, COUNT(DISTINCT a1.id) AS 1st_assists, COUNT(DISTINCT a2.id) AS 2nd_assists FROM people p LEFT JOIN goals g ON (g.player_id = p.player_id) LEFT JOIN goals a1 ON (a1.1st_assist = p.player_id) LEFT JOIN goals a2 ON (a2.2nd_assist = p.player_id) WHERE p.player_id = 4 OR p.player_id = 5 GROUP BY p.player_id;
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| last_name | player_goals | 1st_assists | 2nd_assists |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| Francis   |            5 |           3 |           1 |
| Doe       |            3 |           2 |           2 |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I used your example I got an error: "g.id is an unknown field" so I modified it to see if I could get it to work and I switched g.id, a1.id, a2.id to g.player_id, a1.1st_assist, a2nd_assist as follow: 

SELECT p.last_name, COUNT( DISTINCT g.player_id ) AS player_goals, COUNT( DISTINCT a1.1st_assist ) AS 1st_assists, COUNT( DISTINCT a2.2nd_assist ) AS 2nd_assists
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN goals g ON ( g.player_id = p.player_id )
LEFT JOIN goals a1 ON ( a1.1st_assist = p.player_id )
LEFT JOIN goals a2 ON ( a2.2nd_assist = p.player_id )
WHERE p.player_id =4
OR p.player_id =5
GROUP BY p.player_id

Comment: It seemed to allow the query to go through but the totals are incorrect.  My totals were just 1's across the columns.  I know the database is correct because I can query them 1 at a time and get the correct totals, but only 1 at a time, not spread over the three columns.
Anything else I could be missing?  Thanks for your help, I think we are making big progress. Thanks again.

Comment: What column uniquely identifies a row in the goals table? It is that column you should use in the place of id. Perhaps it is goal_id?

Comment: There is probably a column that is also a primary key for the goals table. That would be what you should use in place of id in the query I wrote.. Let me know if you get it working or have any further trouble.

Comment: I did what you said using the unique identifier from the goals table (goal_id) and it works perfectly now!  Thanks so much!